# Weird Behavior when running Java app

Tags: java, javafx, jar, java-8, executable

The issue:
When Running the Main class the program terminates without doing anything. This only happens when i import libraries to the project, specifically when i import more then 8 libraries. if i remove them from the build path the program loads just fine.

I have tried almost all the combinations to check if it was a specific library, however i found out that it's only the number of libraries that matter.

There are do any errors on the problems tab nor exceptions when running the app. It just terminates.

This are the libraries i'm importing:

- commons-codec-1.10
- commons-io-2.4
- commons-logging-1.1.3
- commons-math3-3.6
- junit-4.12
- log4j-1.2.17
- poi-3.13-beta1-20150723
- poi-excelant-3.13-beta1-20150723
- poi-ooxml-3.13-beta1-20150723
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-beta1-20150723
- poi-scratchpad-3.13-beta1-20150723
- sqljdbc4
- xmlbeans-2.6.0

I have the libraries inside the project, in a folder named lib, and i have already tried to import the libraries by using right click>build path>add to build path, and also buy going to project>right click> build path> configure build path and add the libraries there.

Also i'm using a javafx project and java8.

Comment: how are you running that application??

Comment: any error message is shown?

Comment: there are no errors when running, i've even tried to add a break point in the first line of code and when executing it does not reach it. I'm Running it by pressing the green arrow on eclipse, however i've also tried to go to run configurations and run from there, same thing happens.